# What is the difference between "ĝis" and "al?"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I understand that *ĝis* means "up to", or "as far as", and *al* means "to", but when must one change between the two? Take Duolingo's example:

> Mi vojaĝas tra Germanio ĝis Pollando.

Why would one use *ĝis* here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*al* sets the general direction or target, *ĝis* sets the limit of movement. In some cases you can use any of them, but inserting *ĝis* you actually specify an end point to your movement, so in your example I stop when I reach Polland. Sometimes you can use both at the same time, as found in "La Faraono" (Zamenhof):

> La granda sinjoro elkuris renkonte, **al la monarĥo ĝis la pordego**
>   kaj, demetinte de l’ piedoj multekostajn sandalojn, surgenue helpis
>   Ramzeson malsupreniri.

Comment: Just in order to avoid any uncertainty: _ĝis_ indicates the point in space before you stop, so _tra Germanujo ĝis Pollando_ indicates that the endpoint of the journey is in Germany right at the Polish border.

Comment: Hmm, according to [PMEG](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/rolmontriloj/rolvortetoj/direktaj_rolvortetoj/ghis.html) _ĝis inkluzivas_, i.e. _ĝis Pollando_ means up into Poland but no further. If you want to express, that you stop at the border, then spell it out: _tra Germanio ĝis la limo de Pollando_.